# Read CommandLineArgs in EnvironmentPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When using an `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, is it possible to read the provided `CommandLineArgs`? Since this class is package-private in Spring Boot 2.1, I cannot cast the `PropertySource`´s source to `CommandLineArgs`.

Or in other words: how do I get the keys and values from a `SimpleCommandLinePropertySource`?

Comment: Have you read the [javadoc of CommandLinePropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/CommandLinePropertySource.html) and its super-class [EnumerablePropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/EnumerablePropertySource.html)? If that doesn't help, perhaps you could update your question with some specifics about exactly what you're trying to do and why the mechanisms described in the javadoc don't seem to meet your needs.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks Andy, that worked well for me! I just somehow missed that documented part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AndyWilkinson I figured it out. I can read the environment variable entries like this:

```
private void processEnvVariable(final PropertySource<?> envSource) {
    final CommandLinePropertySource<?> envVariables = (CommandLinePropertySource<?>) envSource;
    if (envVariables.containsProperty("myKey")) {
        doSthUseful(envVariables.getProperty("myKey"));
    } else {
        throw new InvalidParameterException();
    }
}
```